# Parse a complicated .csv in Python

Tags: parsing, pandas

Can't figure out how to get data out of this. I need to get the latitude and longitude.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu0op7yz5glg851/data.csv

So far, I've tried:

```
def main():

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print data

main()
```

and I got this back

```
  Minutes\t                Km/h\tWatts\tKm\tCadence\tHrate\tID\tAlt             Longitude\tLatitude\tms\t TimeStamp
0  2.633\t           \t8.4\t572\t0\t43\t107\t0\t4...                                                       
1  2.667\t           \t10.8\t      \t0.006\t     ...                                                       
2  2.683\t           \t13.9\t572\t0.01\t43\t111\t...                                                       
3  2.7\t           \t17.3\t621\t0.015\t47\t113\t0...                                                       
4  2.717\t           \t23.3\t603\t0.022\t61\t115\...
```

That is not at all what the file actually looks like and I'm lost on how to parse it.

I changed this to use \t as the separator. That helped, but I'm still getting some bad results. For most headings, it returns (using Alt as an example):

```
no items named Alt
```

For Latitude, I'm now getting random values from other columns:

```
2.633                    -34.922394
2.667                 160000.000000
2.683                    -34.922413
2.700                    -34.922420
2.717                    -34.922424
```

Comment: the file is tab separated, use `pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t')` instead

Comment: Thank you. That helped, but I'm still getting some bad results. For most headings, it returns (using Alt as an example):

'no items named Alt'

For Latitude, I get:

Comment: Your file has some missing values that are simply encoded as blank, instead of NaN or something like that. I'm not sure how's the best way to use read_csv out of the box, perhaps just try some other arguments in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html.